# How to use @Value in a static class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a static class in my default class like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static class AnotherClass {
        //HERE I NEED TO USE @VALUE
        //@Value("myBoolean")
        //public boolean myBoolean; //always false, reason of the static class?
    }
}
```

can someone tell why `myBoolean` is always `false` when i try to get this value in static class but when is in normal class then return me a good value? How to get value in static class?
thanks for any answers

Comment: Have you tried annotating the static class as `@Component`?

Comment: no and i can't do this

Comment: How do you get an instance of `AnotherClass`? Also, why do you need a static inner class?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? For now injection into nested class looks like design flaw

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my first glance I would suggest making static *AnotherClass* Spring component by annotating it with *@Component* so Spring can initialize it as bean and then use dependency injection to populate the specific value when it finds the *@Value* annotation.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Component
    public static class AnotherClass {
        @Value("${myBoolean}")
        public Boolean myBoolean;

        @PostConstruct
        void init() {
            System.out.println(myBoolean); // you can see injected value on console
        }
    }
}
```